# Running out the PDF page while generating PDF using iTextSharp.dll

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext

I am generating the PDF using iTextSharp.i have a HTMl Page and i am Reading HTML Page then generate the PDF.but the Problem is that the half of the page is in PDF while another half of the Page is running out the page in PDF.i mean half of the Page is displayed in PDF.while half of the Page is cutting in PDF.

my code is like this in Load Event..

```
    string fileContents;
    string FilePath = Server.MapPath("print-withoutlogin.html");
    StreamReader mstrFileStreamReader = new StreamReader(FilePath);
    try
    {
        fileContents = mstrFileStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
        byte[] result = createPDF(fileContents.ToString()).GetBuffer();

        Response.Clear();
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", result.Length.ToString());
        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("Expires", "0");
        Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "public");
        Response.AddHeader("content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary");
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=kartik.pdf");
        Response.BinaryWrite(result);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        mstrFileStreamReader.Close();
    }
```

and

```
 private MemoryStream createPDF(string html)
 {
    MemoryStream msOutput = new MemoryStream();
    TextReader reader = new StringReader(html);

    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 0, 0, 50, 50);

    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, msOutput);
    HTMLWorker worker = new HTMLWorker(document);
    //worker.SetStyleSheet(styles);


    // step 4: we open document and start the worker on the document 
    document.Open();
    worker.StartDocument();
    // step 5: parse the html into the document      
    worker.Parse(reader);
    // step 6: close the document and the worker     
    worker.EndDocument();
    worker.Close();
    document.Close();

    return msOutput;
 }
```

Comment: So what exactly is the problem?  You have 2 pages of content and only 1 page is being put into the PDF?

Comment: @ramhound:only one page is there..so i can see only half of page..

Comment: Could you provide a sample PDF and the HTML source (and css, too, if applicable)?

Answer (score 0):

Have you Considered using Crystal Reports? I find it much easier and you can use

```
pdfStream = (MemoryStream)report.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
```

Comment: :Can you please give me more detail that what you want to tell me...? i am not exactly getting ...